# Find Moment Generating Function from Probability Mass Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I need help understanding how to find the MGF using a PMF. The PMF is $f(x) = \frac{1}{2^{x-1}}$ when the random variable $X \geq 2$.
I get that you need to multiply $e^{tx}$ by $\frac{1}{2^{x-1}}$. But I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Please provide a bit more information. You say "pmf". So $X$ is a discrete random variable that can take on any integer value $\geq 2$?

Comment: So the question reads: Let X equal the number of flips of a fair coin
that are required to observe the same face on consecutive
flips. Part a ask, find the pmf. Which I did. And part 2 ask to find the moment-generating function of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Bbb E[e^{tX}] = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{e^{tk}}{2^{k-1}} = e^t\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{e^{t(k-1)}}{2^{k-1}} = e^t\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{e^t}{2}\right)^k$$
For $e^t < 2$, this is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) missing the $0^{th}$ term, so:
$$\Bbb E[e^{tX}] = e^t\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{e^t}{2}} -1\right) = e^t \left(\frac{e^t}{2-e^t}\right) = \frac{e^{2t}}{2-e^t}$$
valid on $t < \log(2)$.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're doing. But can you clarify why (e^(t(k-1)))/ 2^(k-1) turns into (e^t/2)^k and not (e^t/2)^(k-1)?

Comment: I shifted indices on the sum. Look carefully at the sum indices, one of the sums starts at $k=2$, the other starts at $k=1$.

Comment: Ohh!  I see! Just to be sure, is that allowed? since x >= 2

Comment: Yes, it is allowed. See this page: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/Series_Basics.aspx, for example (search for the phrase "index shift").

Answer (score 1):

$M_{X}(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$

$\textbf{Discrete case:}$ $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \sum e^{tx}p(x)$

$\textbf{Continuous case:}$ $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \displaystyle \int e^{tx}p(x)\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: I would have to find the integral since x >= 2?

Comment: If $x \geq 2$ is correct, calculate $\displaystyle \int\limits_{2}^{\infty}e^{tx}p(x)\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: No, $X$ is discrete in your case. You calculate the sum $\sum_{x=2}^\infty e^{tx}p(x)$

Comment: @LucasCorrêa See Joshua's comment on the main post above.

Comment: Yes! See the @bames answer.